# C++ syntax class derivation from template with derived class as template parameter

Tags: c++, templates

```
class application: protected manager <application>
{ 
          friend class manager<application>
```

I'm new to C++, but have to understand this from an foreign source-code, which meets my requirements.

What I know up to know: 
The class application is derived from the class manager by the ":". 
"application" in angel brackets means, that the class manager is a template class and application is the template parameter.

But what are the consequences of taking the derived class as template parameter for the base class? I don't understand this.
Can someone explain please?

Comment: Look up CRTP using your favorite search engine.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.